# Redirect 301 With Flags

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Can I use the `Redirect 301` with Flags like NC and L?

For example:

`Redirect 301 /test.htm /example/test/ [NC, L]`

I'm getting server errors but I'm not sure if it's because Redirect 301 doesn't allow flags at the end of the statement or if it's something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flags you mentions are related to mod_rewrite, but `Redirect` is part of mod_alias and has different syntax.

See here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: so mod_alias doesn't have flags, to use no case and last I would have to use mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 3):

As JimDini mentioned you need `mod_rewrite` for those flags. Here is the code that should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^test\.html?$ /example/test/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Yes, the R=301 did the trick. It can even co-exist with subsequent rewrite rules that remap in some way external URLs to internal ones. But to make it work, I had to specify the whole target URL, like this: RewriteRule ^oldpath/oldpage\.html http://%{HTTP_HOST}/newpath/newpage.html [L,R=301]